# PHP Simple array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays

This is driving me crazy and definitely fits into some sort of stupid question category, but for some reason my minds gone completely blank. I KNOW there is a simple way to do this, a default PHP function even, but I can't find it.

If anyone can help, there's some easy points for you.

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    'oauth_consumer_key'        =>  "mykey",
    'oauth_signature'           =>  "mysignature",
    'oauth_signature_method'    =>  "HMAC-SHA1",
    'oauth_timestamp'           =>  1452103343
);
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
echo someFunction($data);
// returns
// 'oauth_consumer_key="mykey", oauth_signature="mysignature", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1452103343"'
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use `array_map()` to loop through keys and values at once, and make an array with `"key => value"` elements, which you then can `implode()` into a comma separated list; If you get stuck, post the attempt here.

Comment: Is there not a built in function similar to http_build_query? I'm sure there is a simpler way, unless i'm going mad

Comment: PHP doesn't provide you: `build_me_a_yellow_pink_striped_house()` function, but it does give you a `hammer()`, `screwdriver()`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple functions you could try.

1. `array_map()` is one of them. You can use this function with a combination of something like `implode()` to get what you want but it is a little complicated since your mind has gone blank haha.
2. `print_r()` will print out your array with keys and values. Simple to use.
3. `var_dump()` same behavior as `print_r()` except it will give you key and value types as well.
4. Or you could use `json_encode()` which will return you as string as you say you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the built-in PHP function print_r. It will pretty-print the array for you.

Or, if you want an in-memory variable, you can do something like:

```
function array_to_string($array) {
    $acc = "";
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $acc = $acc.$key.'='.$value.', ';
    }
    return substr($acc, 0 -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its very simple you can use like that

```
function yourrequirement($yourArr){
    foreach($yourArr as $key => $value){
         echo " ' " .$key. "  = ".'"'.$value.'",'."'";
    }
}

//Call your function
yourrequirement($yourArr);
```